# 1 lettered words with Pig Latin Programming

Tags: java, apache-pig, latin

Whenever I try executing this code, it returns an error whenever I enter a one letter word though the compiling is fine and doing a phrase with any other word more than one letter\

Im confused why this is, because everything should return as fine, but whenever the code goes through a one letter word, it automatically stops the program and ends it

```
import javax.swing.*;
// The "PigTrans" class.
public class PigTrans
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    String userInput;
    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Please enter a word");

    System.out.println (PigTrans.pigTranslator (userInput));

} // main method


public static String pigTranslator (String word)
{


    int[] anArray;
    String phrase = "";
    String[] words = word.split ("\\s+");

    String[] newWord = new String [words.length];


    for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++)


        {
            char number;
            number = words [i].charAt (0);
            int ascii;

            ascii = (int) number;
            if (word.length () <= 1)
            {
                if ((ascii >= 48) && (ascii <= 57))
                {
                    newWord [i] = words [i];
                    phrase = phrase + newWord [i] + " ";
                }
                else
                {
                    newWord [i] = words [i];
                    phrase = phrase + newWord [i] + " ";
                }
            }


            else if ((ascii >= 65) && (ascii <= 90)) //Checks if the word begins with a capital
            {

                char word2;
                word2 = words [i].charAt (0);
                if (startsWithQU (words [i]) == true)
                {
                    newWord [i] = words [i].substring (2);
                    newWord [i] = newWord [i] + "quay";
                }

                else if (checkAscii (word2) == true)
                {
                    newWord [i] = words [i] + "way";
                }
                else
                {
                    String letter = "";
                    letter = words [i].substring (0, 1);
                    newWord [i] = words [i].substring (1);
                    newWord [i] = newWord [i] + letter + "ay";
                }
                String firstLetter, restOfWord, FirstLetter2;
                firstLetter = newWord [i].substring (0, 1);
                restOfWord = newWord [i].substring (1);
                restOfWord = restOfWord.toLowerCase ();
                firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase ();
                newWord [i] = firstLetter.concat (restOfWord);


                phrase = phrase + newWord [i] + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                char word2;
                word2 = words [i].charAt (0);
                if (startsWithQU (words [i]) == true)
                {
                    newWord [i] = words [i].substring (2);
                    newWord [i] = newWord [i] + "quay";
                }

                else if (checkAscii (word2) == true)
                {
                    newWord [i] = words [i] + "way";
                }
                else
                {
                    String letter = "";
                    letter = words [i].substring (0, 1);
                    newWord [i] = words [i].substring (1);
                    newWord [i] = newWord [i] + letter + "ay";
                }
                phrase = phrase + newWord [i] + " ";
            }

        }



    return phrase;
} //pigTranslator


public static boolean checkAscii (char letter)
{
    boolean correct = false; //Declares the boolean variable as false

    int ascii;

    ascii = (int) letter;

    if ((ascii == 65) || (ascii == 69) || (ascii == 73) || (ascii == 79) || (ascii == 85) || (ascii == 97) || (ascii == 101) || (ascii == 105) || (ascii == 111) || (ascii == 117))
    {
        correct = true;
    }

    return correct;
} // PigMethods class

public static boolean startsWithQU (String word)
{
    boolean checkQU = false; //Declares variables needed to check for "qu." Program takes two letters from the word and check if it starts with "qu."
    String QUcheck;

    QUcheck = word.substring (0, 2);

    if (QUcheck.equalsIgnoreCase ("qu")) //When the word starts with "qu, return of boolean value becomes true."
    {
        checkQU = true;
    }

    return checkQU; //If return value is not true, the varuiable returns the value of checkQU.

} //startsWithQU
 } // PigTrans class
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing? What line throws the exception?

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at PigTrans.startsWithQU(PigTrans.java:136)
        at PigTrans.pigTranslator(PigTrans.java:56)
        at PigTrans.main(PigTrans.java:11)

Comment: I tested it and only putting one letter words in works, but putting a one letter and space makes the same error happen

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is with the line:

```
number = words [i].charAt (0);
```

When you put a single letter and then a space, the `split` method creates a 2-element array - first element is the letter and second element is an empty string. So charAt(0) obviously throw an error for the empty string!

**The solution is to `trim` the string before feeding it to the `split` method.**

Also, in the line:

```
if (word.length () <= 1)
```

the condition should probably be `== 1` because you cannot do anything with a 0-length string.